# How to check where a file/directory is referenced from (svn:externals)

Tags: svn, svn-externals

My question concerns the Subversion VCS and the feature of svn:externals. I would like to **find out where a file or directory is referenced from by the externals**.

Not to be misunderstood, I don't want to get a list of externals defined in my working directory, but **a list of directories in the current repository where a selected file or directory is referenced from by svn:externals properties.**

The thing is that when project A is referenced by project B and C, then it seems that only B and C know about that fact, and A doesn't. But when I change project A and recompile it, I want to update and recompile all other projects that are dependent on it to keep them up to date. This is the reason why I'm asking.

My idea was to create a Windows batch file getting a complete list of externals and then filtering it by file or directory name, but that's horrible and lasts forever!

```
set /p filter="File or directory name: "
svn propget svn:externals -R my_repository_address | find "%filter%" /I
pause
```

Thanks!

Comment: However, I'm constantly wondering why such feature is not there. Maybe it is actually unuseful? How then to keep all projects up to date when dependencies get modified?

Comment: Continuous Integration?